# CSS flipping of SVG in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

When I do the following CSS:

```
svg {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

...it works as expected Chrome, but hides the SVG in Firefox (for any negative value). To make it work in Firefox I have to do it like this in HTML:

```
<svg style="transform: scaleX(-1)">
```

Is this expected? Am I missing something?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Would you mind posting a demo (runnable code here, on JSFiddle or the like)? What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Do you have <use> elements, in which case Firefox flips them twice so it looks like nothing happens. The SVG 2 specification says this is wrong but I don't think SVG 1.1 was as clear on the matter.